# Is it possible to embed ASP.NET app in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, wordpress

I have currently a site in wordpress [https://example.com/](https://avsautomotive.com/en/homepage/). Through a "support" page our clients can access a web app at external link www2.example.com/apps/etc.

This process happens with a simple button that opens the app in a new tab.

```
<div align="center">
<button class="button" type="button" 
onclick="alert('The application will open in a new window');openResetEn()">Open App</button>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function openResetEn() {
  window.open("http://www2.example.com/",'targetWindow','toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=760,height=520');
} 
</script>
```

The problem is that i want to keep secret the link from the majority of users that access it.
For example I was thinking if I can open it in a new window that does not shows the link, but I discovered that isn't possible (or is it?).

Then I thought that maybe I can  the app inside the site.

```
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="displayIframe();">The app will open</button>
<div id="iframeDisplay"></div>  
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayIframe() {
        document.getElementById("iframeDisplay").innerHTML = 
\"<iframe sandbox=\"allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms\" 
src=\"http://www2.example.com/\" 
style=\"border:2px solid blue;overflow:hidden;height:520px;width:760px;\"  
scrolling=\"no\" ></iframe>";
    }
</script>
```

But I can't get it to work.
And the reason behind that (i think) is that the site is running at php and the app c#. I found out that you can ran the whole site under asp.net (?!) (PeachPie/WP.NET).

How can I run the app inside the site?